# unable to install rosbash

Tags: ros, rosrun

im trying to execute rosrun but it says i have to install
"apt install rosbash"
but when I try to install it it appears the following error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-catkin-pkg : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
python3-catkin-pkg-modules : Conflicts: catkin but 0.8.10-7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're missing ROS.org packages with upstream packages which is not recommended http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages

You don't clarify how your system is setup. But I see package names from both installation paths. You should pick one. Unfortunately the recommendation path from Ubuntu will always recommend the upstream packages which is likely not what your want if you're using a ROS.org distro you want to install `ros-<ROS_DISTRO>-rosbash` instead.